# StreamWriter Issue: Line breaks

Tags: c#, streamwriter

First let me present the code:

```
 private void AdicionarFormula(string x, string y, string Materia)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("%" + x + " = " + y + "#" + Materia);
        StreamWriter Escritor = new StreamWriter(Properties.Settings.Default.ArquivoDeFormulas, true);
        Escritor.WriteLine("%" + x + " = " + y + "#" + Materia);
        Escritor.Close();
        LerFormulas(true);
    }
```

The issue is: instead of the output being `"%x = y#Materia`" it is actually "

```
%x = y
#Materia"
```

I dont want it to create a new line for "#Materia".

Comment: Looks like the `y` parameter contains a newline... I can't see any other explanation; your code doesn't explicitly add a newline before the `#`

Comment: That is honestly weird, the x and y parameters come from 2 textboxes `AdicionarFormula(xTB.Text, yTB.Text, "a");` I will try to limit the textboxes lines to 1 line only.                   **EDIT**: Limiting the TB's lines to one line only didn't change the output.

Answer (score 1):

Your parameter 'y' contains char a newline. For example, try it in your code:

```
string.Format("%" + x + " = " + y + "#" + Materia).Replace("\n","")
```

Comment: How? The y parameter is obtained through a textbox text, whose line limit is one line.

Comment: @GuilhermeAlmeida, Try method Replace for all strings.